# How can I find Documents with Duplicate Array Elements?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Here is my Document:

```
{ 
   "_id":"5b1ff7c53e3ac841302cfbc2",
   "idProf":"5b1ff7c53e3ac841302cfbbf",
   "pacientes":["5b20d2c83e3ac841302cfbdb","5b20d25f3e3ac841302cfbd0"]
}
```

I want to know how to find a duplicate entry in the array using `MongoCollection` in Java.

This is what I'm trying:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("idProf", idProf);
query.append("$in", new BasicDBObject().append("pacientes", idJugador.toString()));

collection.find(query)
```

Comment: What have you tried? And what exactly do you want to do? Delete the duplicates? Return the duplicates? Are you using the vanilla driver or something like morphia? Please add as much info to your questions as possible, sometimes you can even find an answer yourself in the process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to know only if there are some duplicates (true or false).This is what i'm trying; BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("idProf", idProf);
    
    query.append("$in", new BasicDBObject().append("pacientes",
   idJugador.toString())); collection.find(query);

Answer (score 0):

The best approach really is to compare the length of the array to the length of an array which would have all duplicates removed. A "Set" does not have duplicate entries, so what you need to do is convert an array into a "Set" and test against the original.

### Modern MongoDB `$expr`

Modern MongoDB releases have [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which can be used with aggregation expressions in a regular query. Here the expressions we would use are [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) along with [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) for the boolean comparison:

```
Document query = new Document(
  "$expr", new Document(
    "$ne", Arrays.asList(
      new Document("$size", "$pacientes"),
      new Document("$size",
        new Document("$setDifference", Arrays.asList("$pacientes", Collections.emptyList()))
      )
    )
  )
);

MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();
```

Which serializes as:

```
{
  "$expr": {
    "$ne": [
      { "$size": "$pacientes" },
      { "$size": { "$setDifference": [ "$pacientes", [] ] } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here it is actually the [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) which is doing the comparison and returning only unique elements. The [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) is returning the length, both of the original document array content and the newly reduced "set". And of course where these are "not equal" ( the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) ) the condition would be `true` meaning that a duplicate was found in the document.

The [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operates on receiving a boolean `true/false` value in order whether to consider the document a match for the condition or not.

### Earlier Version `$where` clause

Basically [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is a JavaScript expression that evaluates on the server

```
String whereClause = "this.pacientes.length != Object.keys(this.pacientes.reduce((o,e) => Object.assign(o, { [e.valueOf()]: null}), {})).length";

Document query = new Document("$where": whereClause);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();
```

You do need to have not explicitly disabled JavaScript evaluation on the server ( which is the default ) and it's not as efficient as using [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and the native aggregation operators. But JavaScript expressions can be evaluated in the same way using [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), and the argument in Java code is basically sent as a string.

In the expression the [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) is a property of all JavaScript arrays, so you have the original document content and the comparison to the "set". The [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) uses each array element as a "key" in a resulting object, from which the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will then return those "keys" as a new array.

Since JavaScript objects work like a `Map`, only unique keys are allowed and this is a way to get that "set" result. And of course the same `!=` comparison will return true when the removal of duplicate entries resulted in a change of length.

---

In either case of [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) or [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) these are *computed conditions* which cannot use an index where present on the collection. As such it is generally recommended that additional criteria which use regular equality or range based [query expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) which can indeed utilize an index be used alongside these expressions. Such additional criteria in the predicate would improve query performance greatly where an index is in place.

Comment: I believe OP wants something to check a specific document for duplicates.

Comment: @NestorSokil Maybe, or maybe not. I'm just giving them the option to check the whole collection, or **any** matching predicate. Just as I state, additional criteria can always be added to the predicate. If they want to include a specific document identifier ( i.e the `idProf` for a specific value ) then they can. At any rate there is no need to pull data back to the client just to check for duplicates in the array. That would be a waste of bandwidth. And really messy in general. The statements MongoDB supports are both quite simple.

Comment: just helping to improve your answer :) It may be not obvious for OP that adding `idProf` and handling presence/absence of result is an option.

Comment: @NestorSokil Actually right now I'm wondering what happened to 80% of the answer I posted since it's just not here. There was a lot more detail than I see right now.

Answer (score 0):

We can try to solve this in your Java-application code.

```
private final MongoCollection collection;

public boolean hasDuplicatePacientes(String idProf) {
     Document d = collection.find(eq("idProf", idProf)).first();
     List<String> pacientes = (List<String>) d.get("pacientes");
     int original = pacientes.size();
     if (original == 0) {
         return false;
     }
     Set<String> unique = new HashSet(pacientes);
     return original != unique.size();
}
```

Or if you're searching for a way to do this fully on db-side, I believe it's also possible with something like Neil Lunn provided.